# Jenkins Organization Folder scan doesn't detect repositories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-github-plugin

The Jenkins `Scan Organization Folder Log` looks like this:

```
Started by user Obay Abdelagdir
[Thu Dec 31 16:45:21 UTC 2020] Starting organization scan...
[Thu Dec 31 16:45:21 UTC 2020] Updating actions...
Looking up details of my-org-name...
Organization URL: https://github.com/my-org-name
[Thu Dec 31 16:45:22 UTC 2020] Consulting GitHub Organization
Connecting to https://api.github.com using 94421/****** (Github App, necessary for publishing checks)
Looking up repositories of organization my-org-name
0 repositories were processed
[Thu Dec 31 16:45:23 UTC 2020] Finished organization scan. Scan took 1.3 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Jenkins "Github Organization Folder" details:
I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/docs/github-app.adoc)<strike>, but without installing the "Github App" to the organization (installed on the user)</strike>, and I ignored the `Configuration as Code Plugin` section.

Github App details:
The "Github App" was created with a normal github user, <strike>and it is installed on that user who has owner permission on the organization. Because I couldn't install it on the organization directly.</strike>
**Edit**: I was able to transfer the ownership of the app to the organization and installed it, but the same issue is still there.

My Problem:
It says in the log above `0 repositories were processed`. But I have one branch in the organization, that have a file named `.jenkinsfile` (and yes, I added it to the "Project Recognizers") with the following contents:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Static Code Analysis') {
      parallel {
        stage('Pylint') {
          agent {
            label "pylint"
          }
          steps {
            sh "pylint --exit-zero --load-plugins=pylint_odoo 0-e odoolint --rcfile=./.pylintrc * > pylint.log"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another problem is that the github checks is not working, it gives the following on the build log:

```
[GitHub Checks] Failed Publishing GitHub checks: org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException: https://api.github.com/repos/my-org-name/my-repo {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository"}
[GitHub Checks] Failed Publishing GitHub checks: org.kohsuke.github.GHFileNotFoundException: https://api.github.com/repos/my-org-name/my-repo {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository"}
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

The github app MUST be installed on the organization.
The best (and maybe only) way to do it is as follows:

1. Login with your normal user account
2. Open the organization url, https://github.com/YOUR-ORG-NAME
3. Open the `Settings` tab, the click `Developer settings`
4. Under `Developer settings` there should be two options `OAuth Apps` and `Github Apps`, click on `Github Apps`
5. Then follow the instructions from the plugin docs noramlly.
6. finally make sure to install the app in the organization.